# Does legendary item power scale with difficulty?

Tags: diablo-iii-console

In reference to Diablo 3 on the console (PS3), do more powerful legendary items drop as you go up in master levels 1 to 5 (Inferno mode, of course)? Or are the drops just the same? Obvious example is if a legendary sword drop on master IV is more powerful than say one dropped on master level II, or is it all just random?

Answer (score 1):

The quality of the items (power) remains the same. Just the drop rate of rarer items is increased if you increase the difficulty. The power (item level) depends upon your character level. Same as in PC-version, by the way.